# Unable to fetch data in sails with content-type form-data

Tags: sails.js

Am unable to retrieve form-data in sailsjs, req.params is not working.
But If content-type is application/json then it works

Comment: What does it mean that you are unable?, what are you getting, how does your code looks like? Be more explicit